# add a column and fill his values rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add a column with existing data like this :

```rb
class Migration < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    add_column :models, :c2, :integer
    Model.all.each {|m| m.update!(c2: m.c1 * 2)}
  end
end
```

But it doen't work, all model's c2 column is nil

(rails 6)

thx

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is working, don't understand why but I take it

```rb
class Migration < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    add_column :models, :c2, :integer
    Model.all.each {|m| m.update_column(:c2, m.c1 * 2)}
  end
end
```